# С прописной или строчной? (2)

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Официальное название: ***Академический русский театр имени Евгения Вахтангова***.
Следует ли писать далее по тексту "русский театр" с заглавной?
Буду благодарна за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Академический справочник Лопатина, раздел "Орфография":

> § 190. С прописной буквы пишется первое (или единственное) слово
> усеченного названия, если оно употребляется вместо полного, напр.:
> Государственная дума — Дума, Государственный литературный музей —
> Литературный музей, Центральный дом художника — Дом художника, Большой
> зал Московской консерватории — Большой зал Консерватории, Московский
> государственный институт международных отношений — Институт
> международных отношений.

Таким образом, в вашем случае будет корректно писать *Русский театр*.

Это же подтверждается усечённым наименованием в статьях, опубликованных на официальном сайте этого театра. Цитаты оттуда:

- > Сто пятьдесят лет назад именно с «Маскарада» началась жизнь нашего
  > Русского театра.
- > Вот и сидя в зале нашего Русского театра на премьерном показе
  > «Маскарада» в постановке Изабеллы Каргиновой, внутренне повторял за
  > актерами знакомые строки и слова.
- > Именно этой постановкой полвека назад Русский театр заявил о своем    открытии и как бы прочертил будущую траекторию своего развития:
  > качественная литература, высокий уровень профессионального мастерства, уважение к зрителю.